# Should I use Multiple user models or one big user model in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm doing a Rails project with three user types: students, teachers, and administrators. Each user type has a dozen+ columns unique to that role. Initially I thought I'd create separate models for each type, but having a single shared login seems to pose a problem (I've found a workaround on Stack Overflow, but its complex and a few years old).

What is SOP for situations like this? Is it kosher to have a single user model with 24+ columns that will always be empty depending on the role type? Or am I better off sticking with three separate models and trying to hack a workaround to make a shared login?

Thanks!

EDIT: Oops, forgot to add the third workaround which I'm favoring: having a single user model with only columns relevant to login, and then models for each role that hold columns specific to each user type. Is that a good call?

Answer (score 0):

You could make two separate models, `Student` and `Teacher`.  Then add an `admin:boolean` field for teacher.  I am assuming most admins will probably be teachers?  Even if that is not the case you could just default that all admins are teachers.  Three separate models is terribly bulky.